# Compiling and linking multiple C libraries (stuck at symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64)

Tags: c, lua, linker-errors

I am basically trying to compile the following repo.
https://github.com/zhaozg/lui

The following is where I have reached:
(I am sorry if the steps I am following may be completely wrong as I am new to C and GCC in general, I am just trying my best to bring this puzzle together)

It has two dependencies:

1. https://github.com/andlabs/libui
2. Lua from https://www.lua.org/download.html

I was able to generate two files from the above 2 projects:

1. liblua.a
2. libui.a

I was happy so far, but I am not able to figure out how to use the above .a files and compile the zhaozg/lui project.

The instructions on compiling in github are as follows:

```
gcc -shared -Isrc src/lui.c -I{LUAINCDIR} -I{LIBUVINCDIR} -lui -llua-5.1 -o luv.so
```

Also, I am trying to keep the compiled files locally and not have them copied all over /usr/local

So, After a few hours, I reached the following step:

```
gcc -shared -v -Isrc src/lui.c -I ../lua-src  -I ../libui   /Users/silva/Documents/test00x/lui/liblua.a  /Users/silva/Documents/test00x/lui/libui.a
```

But now I am stuck at the following error:

```
gcc -shared -v -Isrc src/lui.c -I ../lua-src  -I ../libui   /Users/silva/Documents/test00x/lui/liblua.a  /Users/silva/Documents/test00x/lui/libui.a
    Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
     "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.13.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name lui.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target-linker-version 351.8 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0 -I src -I ../lua-src -I ../libui -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/silva/Documents/test00x/lui -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 129 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.13.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/ps/568797890l55qcbrzmcjd6tr0000gp/T/lui-101fc8.o -x c src/lui.c
    clang -cc1 version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1) default target x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     src
     ../lua-src
     ../libui
     /usr/local/include
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/include
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
     /usr/include
     /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
     /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
    End of search list.
    src/lui.c:152:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'luaL_checkint' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          ret = luaL_checkint(L, -1);
                ^
    In file included from src/lui.c:210:
    src/ldraw.c:51:3: warning: implicit declaration of function '_i64toa' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      lua_pushINT64(L, evt->Held1To64);
      ^
    src/ldraw.c:26:23: note: expanded from macro 'lua_pushINT64'
        lua_pushstring(L, _i64toa(n, buf, 10));          \
                          ^
    src/ldraw.c:51:3: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *'
          [-Wint-conversion]
      lua_pushINT64(L, evt->Held1To64);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/ldraw.c:26:23: note: expanded from macro 'lua_pushINT64'
        lua_pushstring(L, _i64toa(n, buf, 10));          \
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/lua.h:228:65: note: passing argument to parameter 's' here
    LUA_API const char *(lua_pushstring) (lua_State *L, const char *s);
                                                                    ^
    In file included from src/lui.c:210:
    src/ldraw.c:796:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'luaL_optint' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      def = luaL_optint(L, -1, def);
            ^
    In file included from src/lui.c:211:
    src/lentry.c:1:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiNewEntry(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lentry.c:10:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiNewPasswordEntry(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lentry.c:19:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiNewSearchEntry(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lentry.c:28:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiEntryText(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lentry.c:51:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiEntryReadOnly(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    In file included from src/lui.c:220:
    src/lmultiline.c:1:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiNewMultilineEntry(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lmultiline.c:10:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiNewNonWrappingMultilineEntry(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lmultiline.c:19:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiMultilineEntryText(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lmultiline.c:30:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiMultilineEntryAppend(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    src/lmultiline.c:48:8: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    static l_uiMultilineEntryReadOnly(lua_State *L)
    ~~~~~~ ^
    14 warnings generated.
     "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 -o a.out /var/folders/ps/568797890l55qcbrzmcjd6tr0000gp/T/lui-101fc8.o /Users/silva/Documents/test00x/lui/liblua.a /Users/silva/Documents/test00x/lui/libui.a -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
          _addCTFeatureEntry in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
          _uiprivOpenTypeFeaturesToCTFeatures in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFArrayGetCount", referenced from:
          _matchStyle in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivMakeVariationAxisDict in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFArrayGetValueAtIndex", referenced from:
          _matchStyle in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivMakeVariationAxisDict in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringBeginEditing", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringCreate", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringCreateMutableCopy", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringEndEditing", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringGetAttribute", referenced from:
          _applyFontAttributes in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _addFontAttributeToRange in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringGetLength", referenced from:
          _applyFontAttributes in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[uiprivTextFrame initWithLayoutParams:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringRemoveAttribute", referenced from:
          _applyFontAttributes in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFAttributedStringSetAttribute", referenced from:
          _processAttribute in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _applyFontAttributes in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _addFontAttributeToRange in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _addBackgroundAttribute in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFDataGetBytePtr", referenced from:
          _trySecondaryOS2Values in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _avarExtract in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFDataGetLength", referenced from:
          _trySecondaryOS2Values in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_CFDictionaryAddValue", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivFontDescriptorToCTFontDescriptor in libui.a(libui-combined.o)


     [removed a few messages in between to keep within stackoverflow limit]

       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenu", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableDictionary", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableString", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNumber", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNumberFormatter", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_uiprivCombinedFontAttr in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_boxChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_buttonDelegateClass in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_checkboxDelegateClass in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_comboboxDelegateClass in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_uiprivDrawTextBackgroundParams in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenPanel", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPopUpButton", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSProcessInfo", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSProgressIndicator", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_intrinsicWidthNSProgressIndicator in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSSavePanel", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSScrollView", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSSearchField", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSSearchField in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSSecureTextField", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSSecureTextField in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSSlider", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSSlider in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSStepper", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTabView", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTabViewItem", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTextField", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSTextField in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTextView", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_intrinsicSizeTextView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTimer", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTrackingArea", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSValue", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_areaView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_boxView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_formChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_formView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_gridChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_gridView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_libuiNSWindow in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSApplication", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_applicationClass in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSButton", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_uiprivFontButton in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSColorWell", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_colorButton in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSComboBox", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSComboBox in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSFontPanel", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_uiprivNonModalFontPanel in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_areaView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_uiprivCombinedFontAttr in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_boxChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_boxView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_buttonDelegateClass in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_checkboxDelegateClass in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_colorButton in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSProgressIndicator", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_intrinsicWidthNSProgressIndicator in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSSearchField", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSSearchField in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSSecureTextField", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSSecureTextField in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSSlider", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSSlider in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSTextField", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_libui_intrinsicWidthNSTextField in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSTextView", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_intrinsicSizeTextView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_areaView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_boxView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_formChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_formView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_gridChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_gridView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_libui_spinbox in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_libuiNSWindow in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
          CFString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          CFString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          CFString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          CFString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          CFString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          CFString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          CFString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "___objc_personality_v0", referenced from:
          _otfArrayForEachAAT in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _doManualMove in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _doManualResize in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "__i64toa", referenced from:
          _l_uiAreaMouseEvent_2_table in lui-101fc8.o
      "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_areaView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_areaView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_uiprivCombinedFontAttr in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_uiprivCombinedFontAttr in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_boxChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_boxChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_boxView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_areaView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_areaView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_uiprivCombinedFontAttr in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_uiprivCombinedFontAttr in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_boxChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_boxChild in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_boxView in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_kCFAllocatorNull", referenced from:
          _uiprivNewGraphemes in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivFontDescriptorToCTFontDescriptor in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivCTFontDescriptorAppendFeatures in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _addCTFeatureEntry in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCFTypeArrayCallBacks", referenced from:
          _uiprivOpenTypeFeaturesToCTFeatures in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivFontDescriptorToCTFontDescriptor in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivCTFontDescriptorAppendFeatures in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _addCTFeatureEntry in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCGColorSpaceSRGB", referenced from:
          _mkcolor in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _fillGradient in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontAttributeName", referenced from:
          _applyFontAttributes in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontFamilyNameAttribute", referenced from:
          _uiprivFontDescriptorToCTFontDescriptor in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivFontDescriptorFromCTFontDescriptor in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontFamilyNameKey", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData familyName] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey", referenced from:
          ___otfArrayForEachAAT_block_invoke in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontFeatureSettingsAttribute", referenced from:
          _uiprivCTFontDescriptorAppendFeatures in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey", referenced from:
          ___otfArrayForEachAAT_block_invoke in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontFormatAttribute", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData prepare] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontFullNameKey", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData fullName] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontRegistrationScopeAttribute", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData prepare] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontSizeAttribute", referenced from:
          _uiprivFontDescriptorToCTFontDescriptor in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontStyleNameAttribute", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData styleName] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontSubFamilyNameKey", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData subFamilyName] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontSymbolicTrait", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData prepare] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontTraitsAttribute", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData prepare] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontVariationAttribute", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData variation] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontVariationAxisDefaultValueKey", referenced from:
          -[fvarAxis initWithIndex:dict:avarTable:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontVariationAxisIdentifierKey", referenced from:
          _uiprivMakeVariationAxisDict in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontVariationAxisMaximumValueKey", referenced from:
          -[fvarAxis initWithIndex:dict:avarTable:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontVariationAxisMinimumValueKey", referenced from:
          -[fvarAxis initWithIndex:dict:avarTable:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontWeightTrait", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData prepare] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTFontWidthTrait", referenced from:
          -[uiprivFontStyleData prepare] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTForegroundColorAttributeName", referenced from:
          _processAttribute in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName", referenced from:
          _uiprivAttributedStringToCFAttributedString in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTUnderlineColorAttributeName", referenced from:
          _processAttribute in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName", referenced from:
          _processAttribute in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_luaL_checkint", referenced from:
          _l_uiAreaSetSize in lui-101fc8.o
          _l_uiAreaBeginUserWindowResize in lui-101fc8.o
          _l_uiAttributedStringInsertAtUnattributed in lui-101fc8.o
          _l_uiAttributedStringDelete in lui-101fc8.o
          _l_uiAttributedStringSetAttribute in lui-101fc8.o
          _l_uiAttributedStringByteIndexToGrapheme in lui-101fc8.o
          _l_uiAttributedStringGraphemeToByteIndex in lui-101fc8.o
          ...
         (maybe you meant: _luaL_checkinteger)
      "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
          -[uiprivCombinedFontAttr hash] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiInit in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiUninit in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _mainStep in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _newItem in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiNewMenu in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
          -[uiprivCombinedFontAttr hash] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiInit in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiUninit in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _mainStep in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _newItem in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiNewMenu in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
      "_objc_enumerationMutation", referenced from:
          _uninitAlloc in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[boxView onDestroy] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[boxView syncEnableStates:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[boxView establishOurConstraints] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[boxView setPadded:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[boxView nStretchy] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[uiprivTextFrame draw:textLayout:at:y:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_objc_getProperty", referenced from:
          -[formChild label] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild baseline] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild leading] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild top] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild trailing] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild bottom] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[gridChild leadingc] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
          _initAlloc in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uninitAlloc in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivAlloc in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivRealloc in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiprivFree in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[areaView initWithFrame:area:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[areaView drawRect:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
          -[areaView initWithFrame:area:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[areaView setFrameSize:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[areaView intrinsicContentSize] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[uiprivCombinedFontAttr init] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[uiprivCombinedFontAttr dealloc] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[boxView initWithVertical:b:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[buttonDelegateClass init] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
          -[areaView drawRect:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[areaView setupNewTrackingArea] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[areaView doMouseEvent:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[intrinsicSizeTextView intrinsicContentSize] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _uiWindowContentSize in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _makeIndependent in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          _doManualMove in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
      "_objc_setProperty_atomic", referenced from:
          -[formChild setLabel:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild setBaseline:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild setLeading:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild setTop:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild setTrailing:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[formChild setBottom:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          -[gridChild setLeadingc:] in libui.a(libui-combined.o)
          ...
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those facing this problem in Mac OS,

`gcc -shared -v -framework Foundation -framework AppKit -Isrc src/lui.c  ...etc`

When using the static library, you have to explicitly link against the system libraries as well,

A static library is just a bunch of .o files; they do not contain any information about external dependencies.